# Need to click the checkbox based on item number

Tags: java, selenium, web

I'm unable to click the checkbox based on item number:

```
List<WebElement> returnItemContainer = driver
                .findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='return-item-select-container']"));

int numberOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='return-item-select-container']")).size();

String ItemNumber = "//li[@class='name'and//p[contains(text(),'Item #" + XLTestData.get("itemId").toString() + "')]]";

for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfElements; i++) {
    if (ItemNumber.contains(XLTestData.get("itemId").toString())) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    }
}
```

Can you tell me that I need to click of the exact item number?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get used to:

1. Add [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) code instead of image
2. Post full [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) or at least make sure that both the [checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) and the text are present

For the time being I can only come up with something generic like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'" + XLTestData.get("itemId").toString() + "')]/ancestor::input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
```

More information:

- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)